# Por que o ProgressBar se esconde atrás do botão?

Tags: android, android-layout

Criei um `RelativeLayout` com um botão e um ProgressBar circular. Desta forma abaixo:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
    android:theme="@style/ButtonStart"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/login" />

  <ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar4"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Independente da ordem, inserindo primeiro o `Button` e depois `ProgressBar`, o vice-versa, depois do projeto compilado, o `ProgressBar` sempre fica atrás do botão. Por que o `ProgressBar` se esconde atrás do botão? Qual melhor forma de resolver este problema?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/38536318/4350835](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38536318/4350835)

Comment: Acredito que para layouts simples como o seu, um FrameLayout basta.

Comment: @LeonardoLima com FramLayout continua o mesmo problema. Talvez o link que você postou, possa até trazer alguma solução. Mas o interessante mesmo seria trazer esse tipo de conteúdo para o SOpt.

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que tu nao está dizendo relativo a que o Progress deve ficar.

Basta adicionar `android:layout_below="@id/btnLogin"` e a magica se realizará.

Outra opçao seria utilizar um `LinearLayout` com orientaçao **vertical.**

Comment: O problema não é esse. O ProgressBar está no mesma posição do botão. Eu não quero colocar o progress abaixo. Quero que ele fique na frente do botão, sobre o botão. É é por esse motivo que estou usando o RelativeLayout.